# OrientDB query too slow

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

OrientDB v2.1.1, 
I have tow class: NOrder and NPassenger, relationship 1 : n, so NOrder has a filed named "passengers",whose type is linklist.

I have two fields (NOrder order_id, NPassenger. Name) index is established

NOrder ducuments count is 3 millon .

I explain these query:

```
 1)select from NOrder where passengers contains(name = 'xxx')
  why this query not involved index .

 2)select from NOrder where 'xxx' in passengers.name
  this query involved indexeses
```

this query cost 120sec .

thanks

Comment: Can you post the results of  "explain select from NOrder where 'xxx' in passengers.name" ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with this structure

```
create class NPassenger
create property NPassenger.name String
create index NPassenger.name on NPassenger (name) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX

create class NOrder 
create property NOrder.order_id String
create property NOrder.passengers linklist NPassenger
create index NOrder.order_id on NOrder (order_id) UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX

insert into NPassenger(name) values ("xxx")  // 12:0
insert into NPassenger(name) values ("Alessandro")  //12:1

insert into NOrder(order_id,passengers) values ("order 1",[12:0])
insert into NOrder(order_id,passengers) values ("order 2",[12:1])
```

Query 1

```
explain select from NOrder where passengers contains(name = 'xxx')
```

[image]

Query 2

```
explain select from NOrder where 'xxx' in passengers.name
```

[image]

None of the two queries use the index because the class target is NOrder.

**UPDATE**

Now I have 50002 NOrder and 50002 NPassenger.
If I execute the queries

`explain select from NOrder where passengers contains(name = 'xxx')`

and

```
explain select from NOrder where 'xxx' IN passengers.name'
```

I get

[image]

this is because no index on the name field is used (because the target class is the Norder class) and then the search is done on all 50002 records of the class Norder.

If I use the query

```
explain select from NPassenger where name = "xxx"
```

[image]

the index NPassenger.name is used because the target class is NPassenger

Comment: You the amount of data is too small, I explain these query, have tips:["Query 'SELECT FROM NOrder WHERE 'xxx' IN passengers.name' fetched more than 50000 records: to speed up the execution, create an index or change the query to use an existent index"], Why query so slowly?